# mongo db-Either all host names in a replica set configuration must be localhost references, or none must be; found 1 out of 2

Tags: mongodb

while adding secondary member in replica set, i get following error:
"Either all host names in a replica set configuration must be localhost references, or none must be; found 1 out of 2"
my first machine configuration is:[image]

[image]

[image]

second node config:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Please do not post images. Instead post the actual code/text in your answer. It makes for hard reading if you have to click on pictures and the text is not re-usable. Another benefit is the fact that you can remove data you don't want in the text instead of trying to colour over images. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have remowed 127.0.0.1 from configuration on both sides and instead i have just used ip's and the problem has solved.
1 node configuration: cat/etc/mongod.conf

net:
port: 27017
bindIp: 10.10.24.17
cat/etc/hosts
##127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
#::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.10.24.17 mongo01.barva.info mongo01
10.10.24.18 mongo02.barva.info mongo02

2 node config:
cat/etc/mongod.conf

net:
port: 27017
bindIp: 10.10.24.18
cat/etc/hosts
##127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
#::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.10.24.17 mongo01.barva.info mongo01
10.10.24.18 mongo02.barva.info mongo02.
when connecting to mongo shell, I am using $mongo 10.10.24.17 , rs.add("mongo02") command works . by the way the version of mongo is 4.4.4. hope this will help others too.
@JJussi thanks for yuor answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can have all replica set nodes in the same physical computer (localhost), but in different ports! (node1:27017, node2:27027, ...)

You CANNNOT have different RS nodes:

- at one machine at same port (f.ex. 27017)
- different machine and bind to localhost address

So, you need to build your replica set using IP-addresses.

Comment: i have changed 127.0.0.1 with ip but then can not start mongo

Comment: What is your current configuration of those nodes. Node1 - IP, port  Node2 - IP, port?